# Linear Independence & Integral Homology Cobordism Group

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, cobordism

The set of integral homology spheres up to integral homology cobordism forms
an abelian group with the operation induced by the connected sum. This group is called ***integral homology cobordism group*** and is denoted by $\Theta^3_{\mathbb Z}$. There are several linear independence arguments for $\Theta^3_{\mathbb Z}$:

**I. Based on gauge theory:**

1. [Furuta](https://eudml.org/doc/143788)
2. [Fintushel-Stern](http://faculty.sites.uci.edu/rstern/files/2011/03/28_Inst_Homology.pdf)
3. [Daemi](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.08176.pdf)

**II. Based on Floer theory:**

1. [Stoffregen](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.01286.pdf)
2. [Dai-Manolescu](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.02020.pdf)
3. [Hendricks-Hom-Lidman](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.02008.pdf)
4. [Lin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.01637.pdf)

Is there another linear independence argument related to $\Theta^3_{\mathbb Z}$?